# Number of realizations in a roulette to assure a condition with a given probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Having a perfect roulette, we know that `p = q = 18/37` and `r = 1/37`, where `p`is the probability of getting a red, `q` getting black and `r` getting `0`.

Then you know that if `N->infinity` (number of realizations), the number of reds (`P`) will be `P=N*p` (same for blacks `Q=N*q` and zeros `R=N*r`).

The question is: what should be the value of `N` to be sure with a probability of `x` that `P in [N*p - e, N*p + e]`, with an arbitraryly low integer `e` (e.g., 1)?

In other words: how many realizations should be done so that you can be sure that results will start to be the expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exact computation would be difficult.

However, if you are ok with approximations, then note that the number of reds $R$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $Np$ and variance $Np(1-p)$. [(Normal approximation.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)

Then $$\mathbb{P}(Np-\epsilon< R < Np+\epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(-\epsilon< (R-Np) < \epsilon) \approx \Phi(\epsilon/\sqrt{Np(1-p)})-\Phi(-\epsilon/\sqrt{Np(1-p)})
= 2\Phi(\epsilon/\sqrt{Np(1-p)})-1.$$
Setting this equal to some probability $x$ and solving for $N$ will give you what you want.

Comment: What does phi stands for?

Comment: @CarlosNavarroAstiasarán It is the CDF of the standard normal distribution: $\Phi(t) = \mathbb{P}(Z \le t)$ where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. We are using the fact that $\frac{R-Np}{\sqrt{Np(1-p)}}$ is [approximately] standard normal.